# Least invasive way to use nanotime() entry/exit points in a class?

Tags: java, profiling, overloading

I have a MVC application in Java swing, and I'd like to measure the `nanotime()` at various entry an exit points in the codebase.  As a toy example, consider a class `Foo`, with methods A through Z:

```
public class Foo(){
    private void A(){
       do task A1()
       do task A2()
    }
    private void B(){...}
    ....
    private void Z(){ 
       do task Z1()
       do task Z2()}
 }
```

I need to modify methods A() and Z() to output nanotime() as such:

```
public class Foo(){
    private void A(){
       do task A1();
       do task A2();
       System.out.println("Entry time: " + System.nanotime());
    }
    private void B(){...}
    ....
    private void Z(){ 
       do task Z1();
       do task Z2();
       System.out.println("Exit time: " + System.nanotime());
       }
 }
```

The problem is that I'd like to do this profiling without altering my source code for Foo().  In reality, I need to do more than just print the nanotime, and the profiling would clutter up the actual method logic; I can't think of practical way to do this.  One approach is to subclass Foo(), and overload the methods; however, this seems heavy-handed, as there are several other classes in the codebase that need such treatment.  I don't want to make 4 new subclasses just add tracepoints in the code.

In Python, I could overload these methods at runtime (monkey-patching), and encapsulate this in some profiler object.

Are there any frameworks/approaches in Java to do something similar?  I've seen dynamic proxies, but don't quite understand if they're suited for something like this.

Comment: Dynamic proxies are based on *interfaces*.  You cannot proxy for a class without subclassing it.  A proxy-based approach would also depend on there being a means to inject the proxies in place of the regular application objects.  If your code is not built with something along those lines in mind then retrofitting it with support is distinctly non-trivial.

Comment: You might consider looking into an aspect-oriented programming framework such as [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/), which has been adopted into the Eclipse project.

Comment: You could also look into using [JVMTI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jvmti/) to assist you with your profiling.  It is a standard toolkit that has profiling support among its core purposes.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  Appreciate it